# Publishing Visual Studio19 Blazor Webassembly Sample App to Localhost

Tags: iis, blazor, webassembly, publishing

im new to blazor webassembly. thank you for your help in advance.
im trying to deploy the VS19 blazor assembly canned app to my windows 10 IIS v10. i added the .Net Core 5.08 sdk to my computer.
i set up a new site with port for the blazor assembly publish files. the app pool is no managed code and integrated.
when i try to get to the files on my browser via \localhost:PortNumber, I get the following error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAFEs.jpg)

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'http://localhost:XXXX/_framework/wasm/dotnet.timezones.dat' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'xI7/FN7+KDR20t/V+GA9QSjyAcAQM0u8xSBKmkG+cGQ='. The resource has been blocked.
localhost/:1
Unknown error occurred while trying to verify integrity.
blazor.webassembly.js:1
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: You can try to add <BlazorCacheBootResources>false</BlazorCacheBootResources> in csproj file. It will ignore integrity checks. And don't forget to clear cache and cookie in browser. What about deploy an empty application on IIS? Does it report same error?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.
i replaced the vs 19 blazor canned app with an empty .net app. IIS had no problems. i added a html page. IIS had no problem. I added a webform.aspx. again, iis had no problem. 
i changed the IIS root directory from point to the blazor wwwroot folder to pointing the folder holding wwwroot folder. I received an error something about missing css files. i corrected the link then
the error changed a HTTP Error 500.19 Internal Server Error. 
App pool is set to no managed code and integrated services. Could it be an app pool error?

Comment: The possibility of problems with the application pool is very small. But IIS should indeed point to the folder containing the blazor wwwroot folder, not blaozr wwwroot. About 500.19, did you set the security in the properties of folder? The easiest way is add "EveryOne" and set it full control. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SWqe.png

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll give it a try and get back to you. Again, many thanks.

Comment: I added Everyone with Full Control and no luck. I did find another stack overflow article about a similar issue.
here's a link to it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67388120/deploy-web-api-blazor-wasm-on-ubuntu-integrity-issue-of-wasm?rq=1

any idea how i can check out if i'm blocking dlls? thx

Comment: after more searching on stack overflow, i got it to work. i'll add the links
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65110243/blazor-webassembly-publish-failed?rq=1
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62063983/cant-run-published-blazor-webassembly-app?rq=1